# Azure Web App deploy.cmd disappearing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've created my own `deploy.cmd` for customizing my app's behavior when pulling new code but, unfortunately, I can't see it in the `site\deployments\tools` folder where it usually belongs.

Typically, the file is auto-generated and placed in the tools folder automatically and I've been successfully modifying it. I've been advised to simply place it in the root of my repository and it will be handled automatically. After doing that, I'm unable to find the `deploy.cmd` file in the expected place.

Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal for it not to be there when you use a custom deployment script. It only ends up there when your script is *generated*.

Generally speaking, you should *never* modify this file when you see it in the tools folder. It is stored there as a cache for the system. You either use a custom deployment script, or you end up using the generated one.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you forgot to add a `.deployment` file alongside `deploy.cmd`. Without it, it will be ignored. It should contain:

```
[config]
command = deploy.cmd
```

See this [post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/) for details.

Comment: I definitely do have the `.deployment` file going along with it. I can confirm that the `deploy.cmd` had the desired effect, I just don't see it in the `tools` dir

Comment: Why do you want it in the tools dir? That is an implementation detail. It is not supposed to be there when you have a custom deployment script.

Comment: If that's the intended behavior, then that's fine with me :)

Comment: I added a separate answer now that issue is understood. You can ignore this one and accept the other one.